# Url validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working in a module that had the option to enter five website urls. So i need validation for those input fields. I tried to find out some plugins but didn't find anything so I'm trying to build a custom validation.I tried some code. Actually what I'm trying to achieve is that when a user enters a url into this 5 input fields i need to check whether any of this object in the array exists in the url .

```js
function savewebsite(){
    var cars = ["facebook", "amazon", "instagram", "twitter", "youtube", "paypal", "twitch", "tiktok", "cash.app", "onlyfans", "skype", "gofundme", "manyvids", "snapchat"];
    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
            if ($('#sociallink'+j).val().indexOf(cars[i]) > -1) {
                return false;
                // alert("hai");
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check whether the item exists in array, then just use `some` method:

```
let val = ($('#sociallink'+j).val();
var isThere = cars.some(s => s === val )
```

An example:

```js
let val = 'skype';
let cars = ["facebook", "amazon", "instagram", "twitter", "youtube", "paypal", "twitch", "tiktok", "cash.app", "onlyfans", "skype", "gofundme", "manyvids", "snapchat"];
let isThere = cars.some(s => s === val);
console.log(isThere);
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to check whether string contains another string, then you can use `includes` method:

```js
let val = 'skype.com';
let cars = ["facebook", "amazon", "instagram", "twitter", "youtube", "paypal", "twitch", "tiktok", "cash.app", "onlyfans", "skype", "gofundme", "manyvids", "snapchat"];
let isThere = cars.some(s => val.includes(s));
console.log(isThere);
```

Comment: I've checked this but this will work only when we use exact word " example ". What i actually need is if user enters http://example.com this url need to check with the item in the array.